# Failed to locate executable /~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/bin/node: No such file or directory

Tags: path, aws, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

What is supposed to be the appropriate node executable path to use. My machine runs on windows but i am using Amazon linux as the app is hosted on an AWS EC2 intance. Whenever i start the app from systemd and i used the node path gotten from amazon linux when i `which node` i get the error: `Failed to locate executable /~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/bin/node: No such file or directory` i have tried a few other path patterns but still to no avail.
Here is my etc/systemd/system/node-api.service

```
[Unit]
Description=My App
Documentation=https://example.com
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ec2-user
ExecStart=/~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/bin/node /home/ec2-user/code/myapp/v1-sub/app.js
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Please what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The lead forward slash should not be there.

Comment: The service won't start without the lead '/', it gives the file a bad unit file setting. What is my machine's equivalent of /usr/bin/node ?

Comment: The tilde is not being expanded. Use the full path to the `node` command.

Comment: The tilda `~`, should be the first character, but may not be expanded, depending on tool. It (the `~`) represents the current user's home directory.

Comment: Found and used the full path and it worked now. Thanks a lot guys! I appreciate